# MacBook that spontaneously restarts and often shuts down instead of sleeping

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

[image]

My Macbook Pro has started shutting down rather than sleeping when I close it and it just decides to shut down in the middle of an operation and restart. When I ran Repair Disk Permissions on Disk Utility this is the result.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I would go for my 'make sure it's all OK' recipe for starters...

- Fix permissions *[which you did already]*, Verify & if necessary Repair disk, using Disk Utility
- Reset Home folder permissions & ACLs using [OnyX](http://www.titanium.free.fr/onyx.html)  - Maintenance tab/permissions, tick the box at the top then Execute.
- Update or [re-apply if already updated] to 10.10.5 using the [10.10.5 combo update](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1832), not the delta from App Store